# How to disable Pay Later payment option in Razorpay react-native

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am using [react-native-razorpay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-razorpay) in my application.
I want to hide some payment methods on the Razorpay payment page.

I am able to hide or disable **Net Banking** and **Wallet** options but the **Pay Later** option doesn't disable.

This the code i used

```
  var options = {
    image: '',
    currency: 'INR',
    key: '***********',
    amount: Amount,
    name: 'MY APP',
    prefill: {
      email: Email,
      contact: Number,
      name: Name
    },
    theme: {color: 'red'},
    method: {
      netbanking: false,
      card: true,
      wallet: false,
      upi: true,
      paylater: false
    },
  }

  RazorpayCheckout.open(options).then((data) => {})
```

How to hide or disable **Pay Later** payment option in react-native-razorpay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config: {
      display: {
        hide: [
        { method: 'paylater' },
        { method: 'emi' }
      ],
      preferences: { show_default_blocks: true }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

**[Native Android] [Java/Kotlin]**

Spent a whole day searching, but nothing worked. But, finally found the solution. Hope it will help someone.

You can use the following implementation to hide the particular option in Android.

```
        JSONObject configObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject displayObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray hideObj = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject methodObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject preferencesObj = new JSONObject();

        preferencesObj.put("show_default_blocks", "true");
        methodObj.put("method","paylater");
        hideObj.put(methodObj);
        displayObj.put("hide", hideObj);
        displayObj.put("preferences", preferencesObj);
        configObj.put("display",displayObj);

        options.put("config", configObj);

        checkout.open(activityContext, options);
```